# Fetch all email from Gmail account

Tags: ios, objective-c, email, gmail-api

I can get the Information of user data and email address from google api with help from [this link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/accessing-google-services-using-the-oauth-20-protocol--mobile-18394).

But my task is to get all user mails from a Gmail account, and display them in a table view.

I checked the [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/) but can't get enough reference.

Is there any way to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to look into `threads`. While normally a programmer would probably think of background processes when talking about threads, Google refers to "groups" of messages as threads (how it groups an email and replies into a single message in the client). While the [API Reference for threads](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/list) has an example in Java, it shouldn't be too hard to translate it into Obj-C if you're already set up to make other calls to the Google API.

Specifically, look into the `list` method (linked above). Alternatively, you could use `messages.list` but they will be much less organized. Also know that I'm pretty sure you'll need to increase the `maxResults` as I believe the default max is 100.

Comment: I have done it with :
Scope :: https://mail.google.com/    //for full gmail access &
callApi : "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/my_email_address@gmail.com/messages

but it always give error as following:

 {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
    "message": "Insufficient Permission"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Insufficient Permission"
 }
}

Comment: i made different app from different gmail a/c and the problem is solved with same code

Comment: Ever figure out the insufficient permissions error?  that seems odd, are you sure you're trying the right email address?  maybe just use "me" for the email address instead (the default).